Ghost PWM Signals
I am an electronics engineering student currently working on a BLDC motor driver project with my team. My role is in software development. We are using the STM32F100RB microcontroller and coding it in bare metal.
My question is: when we tried to create a PWM signal with the controller and observed it with a logic analyzer, we saw a proper 16 kHz PWM signal with a 50% duty cycle. However, we couldn't see it with the oscilloscope, and when we tried to inspect the signal with an LED, it didn't turn on. Later, while debugging, I realized that I had configured the GPIO registers incorrectly.
After I fixed it, we saw the same signal on the logic analyzer, but this time, we could also see it on the oscilloscope and the LED. This doesn't make sense to me. If there wasn't a voltage change on the pins, how did the logic analyzer detect it?

So how it was configured incorrectly? Was it perhaps open-drain output?

let me check @Justme

@Justme yes it was Alternate function open-drain output mode how did you know

@ChesterGillon my logic analyzer is a chinese knock-off version of one of saleae logic analyzers I bought it around 7 dollars really dont know about its hardware.

@ChesterGillon So here is a question if I was keep the GPIO in open-drain mode and try to read the output with a pull-up resistor would the oscilloscope be able to read it?

Rynxie: If the GPIO is open-drain mode, your LED won't light if connected to GND. But if connected between GPIO and +3.3 Vdd it should - so long as you drive its cathode with GPIO, and its anode (through a current-limiting resistor to Vdd. This is actually the preferred way to drive a LED from a microcontroller GPIO

The Saleae First-Generation Logic contains:

The original Logic is the only Saleae device to have internally pulled up inputs. All other Saleae devices had an internal resistance to ground. The original Logic's inputs float at about 2.4 volts, with over 100 K ohms of pull-up resistance, producing a very small pull-up effect.

Perhaps the chinese knock-off version has done the same as the Saleae original Logic. That could explain why with the GPIO set to open-drain mode the logic analyzer was able to show the PWM signal.
If you connect the oscilloscope to the input of the logic analyser, you should be able to measure the pull-up voltage in the logic analyser to confirm this.
And if the oscilloscope and logic analyser are both connected at the same time, and the GPIO left as open-drain, then the oscilloscope and logic analyser will probably both show the PWM signal.

From measurement, the Chinese ones have an internal pullup to 3.3V equivalent to about 2.7kΩ. I have a real Saleae "Logic" 8-input, resplendent in its Applesque packaging, which does not have that (or if there is it's more like 10MΩ- floats at about 2.5V.  Both work well with Pulseview open-source software but I usually use the knock-off one (with good grippers that cost many times as much as the analyzer).

As the MCU was configured for open-drain output, it can pull signal only to 0V.
Many ICs, including the STM32, have internal software controllable pull-ups. The logic analyzer input is high if nothing is connected. So the weak pull-up pulls the signal high when MCU does not pull it low. This is why the logic analyzer can detect it.
Oscilloscopes do not pull the signal high, but to ground, so it can detect nothing about an open-drain output. Unless you have the logic analyzer also connected to pull high. But the scope will also pull low with the impedance of the scope itself and the 10x probe.

Thanks a lot. I am learning new things

When you are generating PWM signals, configure the pins in push pull mode which is it to disable the internal pull up resistor on the pins. In this way, you will see the PWM signal only when PWM is enabled on those pins. Open drain mode on the PWM channel pins doesn't make sense as you dont want the pins to be high when the PWM signal has a low output. The internal pull up tries to make the voltage level on those pins high which is not required all the time. A high on the pins would be interpreted as 100% duty cycle by any PWM slave device which uses PWM signals.
